# why smp_rmb is not preceding load operation?

Tags: c, linux, queue, kernel

there is a code as below in the version 2.6.24 of kernel:

```
unsigned int __kfifo_put(struct kfifo *fifo,
             unsigned char *buffer, unsigned int len) {

    unsigned int l;

    len = min(len, fifo->size - fifo->in + fifo->out);

    /*
     * Ensure that we sample the fifo->out index -before- we
     * start putting bytes into the kfifo.
     */

    smp_mb();

    /* first put the data starting from fifo->in to buffer end */
    l = min(len, fifo->size - (fifo->in & (fifo->size - 1)));
    memcpy(fifo->buffer + (fifo->in & (fifo->size - 1)), buffer, l);

    /* then put the rest (if any) at the beginning of the buffer */
    memcpy(fifo->buffer, buffer + l, len - l);

    /*
     * Ensure that we add the bytes to the kfifo -before-
     * we update the fifo->in index.
     */

    smp_wmb();

    fifo->in += len;

    return len;
}
```

my question is why `smp_mb()` is not preceding getting `fifo->out` value (namely, `len = min(len, fifo->size - fifo->in + fifo->out)`, but behind it?

Comment: The comment is clear. The barrier is between the load and the store

Comment: _Side note:_ 2.6.x is circa 2004. That's 20 years old. A _lot_ has changed since then. Would studying a more recent version (e.g. 5.x.y) be more valuable?

Comment: i mean why read barrier is not preceding getting value(namely smp_mb is not preceding out) ?